# How can I extend the lifetime of a struct so that I can call tokio::run with it?

Tags: rust

I have a function which works:

```
extern crate tokio;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Interval;

fn run(label: String) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(1000))
        .for_each(move |instant| {
            println!("fire; instant={:?}, label={:?}", instant, label);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("interval errored; err={:?}", e))
}

fn main() {
    tokio::run(run("Hello".to_string()));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=339511b4537da80c308e715ceca10d2e)

I'd like to create a struct which would hold some parameters (`label`) in this case with a method `run` which would utilize the parameters:

```
extern crate tokio;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::timer::Interval;

struct Ir {
    label: String,
}

impl Ir {
    fn new(label: String) -> Ir {
        Ir { label }
    }

    fn run(&self) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + '_ {
        Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(1000))
            .for_each(move |instant| {
                println!("fire; instant={:?}, label={:?}", instant, self.label);
                Ok(())
            })
            .map_err(|e| panic!("interval errored; err={:?}", e))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ir = Ir::new("Hello".to_string());
    tokio::run(ir.run());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3ee25a831442010ab1a53ae881506544)

What I get is:

```
error[E0597]: `ir` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:16
   |
28 |     tokio::run(ir.run());
   |                ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
29 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I've read "Advanced Lifetimes" and "Validating References with Lifetimes" from "Rust by Example", but I still don't understand how to fix it.
Why doesn't `ir` live long enough?
I've created it in the same scope where I'm trying to call `ir.run()`, so I would assume it would stick around.

Comment: run from tokio require that lifetime is static, https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/tokio/runtime/fn.run.html.

Comment: So the signature should be `fn run(&self) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static {` ?

Comment: I think but I'm clearly not enough skilled, that run must consume `self` and not take it as reference.

Comment: @Stargateur you were right, consuming `self` solved the problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you rewrite:

```
tokio::run(ir.run());
```

as:

```
tokio::run(Ir::run(&ir))
```

The error becomes a little clearer:

```
error[E0597]: `ir` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
28 |    tokio::run(Ir::run(&ir));
   |                        ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
29 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Since [`tokio::run`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1/tokio/runtime/fn.run.html) requires a `'static` lifetime for the Future:

```
pub fn run<F>(future: F) 
where
    F: Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send + 'static,
```

To avoid lifetime issues consider consuming the `Ir` value:

```
fn run(self) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()>  {
    Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_millis(1000))
        .for_each(move |instant| {
            println!("fire; instant={:?}, label={:?}", instant, self.label);
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("interval errored; err={:?}", e))
}
```

Comment: Yes, that made it work, and more importantly I now understand why it needs to be this way!